# How to get exclusivity on stdout

Tags: terminal, stdout

This is a simple question but I couldn't find any thing about this:

How can a program get exclusivity on stdout at current virtual terminal?

I.e.: When running two tasks only one should be able to write to stdout. (like a full screen ncurses installer).

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to prevent a background job from messing up your terminal, redirect its stdout and stderr elsewhere: `prog >logfile 2>&1 &`. Or use something like tmux or screen, and instead of running it in background, run it in a different window. You can also use `stty tostop`, which will cause a background job which tries to write to the tty to be *stopped* (by the SIGTTOU signal), but I fail to see what advantage that has over just redirecting its output elsewhere: if a background job turn out unexpectedly garrulous, you can stop it by hand with fg and Ctrl-Z.

Comment: I can't control which jobs will be running, some administrator background jobs show messages on stdout eventually. Using `stty tostop` will stop the job execution, or just ignore it's output?

Comment: `stty tostop` will cause a background job (a group of processes running in the same terminal & part of the same session as your shell) to be stopped by a SIGTTOU signal (not a SIGTSTP signal) when it tries to write to the terminal. It will **not** prevent the sysadmin from clobbering your terminal via wall(1) or other means. Example: open two terminal emulators, get the name of the terminal in one with `tty` (e.g. `/dev/pts/9`), and then from the other run `echo HEY > /dev/pts/9`. A regular user has no way to prevent that.

Comment: @pizdelect `root` processes cannot be stopped but for all others see the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stty tostop` setting makes the kernel send `SIGTTOU` to background processes which try to write to the terminal. A process can ignore that signal, though.

An alternative might be to connect the application to an unused virtual console. Create a new user for that, make the terminal accessible only for that user and run the program as that user.

**edit**

It is much easier: You do not need (in practice) a different user. You just need a currently unused terminal. In general no other process of the same user will use that terminal but you can prevent all but root processes from writing there by executing `chmod 000 /dev/tty`. That is no problem for the running shell and its future child processes as the file descriptor has already been opened and is inherited by the children.

In theory processes of the same user could restore the permissions but they are not going to do that.

Comment: SIGTTOU not SIGTSTP. SIGTSTP is generated by Ctrl-Z.